CSS styling help for scrollable content
I am using below styles to show chat history for my BOT:
.chat-history {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allows items to wrap onto multiple lines */
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  max-width: calc(1200px - 10px); /* Adjust the value as needed */
  margin: 5px; /* Provides spacing between items */
  overflow: auto; /* Scrollable content */
}

However, I want to be able to allow users to scroll up and down to see the full chat history. Currently the entire content shows up which keeps making the page really long. When I try to specify a height using height: 300px; some of the older content from the chat history is not rendering to the page.

Better make a Minimal Reproducible Example

The overflow:auto does exactly that, as long as you don't have flex-direction: column which makes it scroll on the x-axis.


.chat-history {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: calc(1200px - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
}
<div class="chat-history">
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>
  <p>He is not a civil servant but works for the state.</p>

</div>



